# Why do I encounter an out of memory error on a linux vm but it works on a normal Windows 10?

Tags: java, linux

My command line java program works when run on a Windows 10 workstation with a dual core CPU with 1GB RAM allocated.

However, it encounters an out of memory error when I run it on a Ubuntu virtual machine with four vCPUs with 12GB RAM.

Both are run using -Xms and -Xmx set accordingly to the same value.

This is a strange error.

UPDATE:
1) I can't share the code and not to sound arrogant or anything but I think there is nothing wrong with the code.

2) The error is as follows:

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 12288 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2627), pid=22403, tid=0x00007f52f9f2c700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
```

Btw, my vm's max memory is 12GB and I used -Xms12160m -Xmx12160m.
As for my workstation, my max memory is 2GB but I used -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m

Comment: Hard to help you without seeing some code.

Comment: Can you please give some additional information? Like what your program does? Or posting the error

Comment: I realize you have a good answer, but I thought I'd point out another possible cause: Something like this happened to me with a program that used many file handles for network I/O.  It may no longer be this way, but at the time Linux (by default) could handle 2-3 thousand file handles and windows could handle 20,000 or so.  When Linux ran out of file handles, you got a very misleading "Out of Memory" condition in Java (which I thought of when I saw your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems to me on the Linux system you are asking it to reserve the full 12 MBs as the initial heap size; this is not really practical as it obviously needs memory for other stuff (code, operating system etc).

From other questions on SO it seems clear that the defaults for minimum is something like 1/64th of the physical RAM.